# How i can get data from json file using ajax

Tags: json, ajax, spring, long-polling

i am  try to realize Ajax Long Polling in my project
this structure of my project
[str](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmWZS.png)
in json file i have this code

```
{"user": "user","two": "two","three": "three"}
```

When i am  try run my project, i get his in idea console:

```
WARN 8032 --- [nio-8080-exec-3].w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "status"
```

and this in chrome console:
[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLOT4.png)

I will be grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript file doesn't include jQuery library. 
you can include this before bootstrap library ( depend on jQuery ).

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your error trace provided here, you're providing non numeric value to `status` field which is not transforming into `Long`. Due to this `NumberFormatException` raised.  You can add @ExceptionHandler either in your controller or can define a global exception handler using @ControllerAdvice to handle the exception and send appropriate response message and status code.

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ApiExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handlerGenericError(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object>handlerBadRequest(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchExceptionex){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.This solution relieves me from `NumberFormatException ` but Unfortunately not solve my problem